# Android Menu Labels

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create such labels like in this example? I mean the `Spades w/ Ads` and these `Spades Settings` and `Partners Spades Options`?

[image: Example Menu]

Comment: are you just want to know the labels  concept or you are creating the activity like as above image ?

Comment: Actually I just need to "separate" different areas. I am not really familiar with Android as I am with Java. In Java I would say, I want to put several JPanels on a JFrame and separate each with a TitledBorder.  I don't think, preferences are right for me in this case.

Comment: so your activity is no having check-box and all like above?

Comment: It does, but I don't really need to "save" settings for the next use, only separate them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant OfirAN answered for some thing else as per mis-understanding the question...

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh, user1170330 It's not what I thought would happen, I just wanted to point something, not that user1170330 will change his accepted answer. Please accept Dheeresh Singh's answer.

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh Thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy with Shared Preferences, take a look at this [tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/tag/sharedpreferences/)

In brief: for all Preference Category you have the possibility to add a title, in your case Spades Settings and Partners Spades Options.

Answer (score 0):

Spades w/ Ads is the title of the screen and rest can be easily created using xml............

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff555555"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="sample1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to create the rest using xml?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-building-application-preference-screens/

Comment: Ah, this is just a simple TextView? I thought, it would be something like a TitledBorder in Java, for separating JPanels...

Comment: yes, you change any thing here like  color, size , padding , bgcolor and all.....

Comment: a bit different link  but this will help you more to create this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: are you just want to know the labels concept or you are creating the activity like as above image ? –

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh That is not OK to give one answer and then change it to the answer that other people gave. that's not the purpose of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @OfirAN : I think the question is regarding only label even I asked the same in comment in question, so I gave the answer as per question and suggested some thing if (only guessing) he is making the Preference like activity but as I am not sure even now for same so I only suggested that but in answer I have not talked any thing about Preference like activity. I have not changed my answer yet Please see......... and you have already down-voted me due to your confusion. Please wait till the answer of user1170330 on my question.

Comment: @OfirAN: As It is simple that image in question indicates it should be Preference activity and there is nothing that only you used the Preference activity even I used the same........ So I can also suggest the same but answer is still same not linked or biased with you answer.

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh I'm sorry for down-voted you, but this community is honest, and if one person gave his answer, this is his answer and all the others can give other possibilities and not the same, a specifically after they gave their first answer. Never mind, no hard feelings.

Comment: So let user1170330 to decide which answer he understands more.... And there may be two almost answer same but which makes asking person comfortable should get preference. I answered what he is asking and then suggested (only suggested ) Preference like activity if he need that also......

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh user1170330 already decided. Again, Think for a second, if everybody will gave their answer and then change it to the exactly same answer as other user give, this all community will be useless. Enjoy from your reputation points and have a lovely day.